# What's the proper way of notifying a RecyclerView adapter about changes in non-visible items?

Tags: android, cursor, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'll try to be as specific as possible. I have a cursor-backed RecyclerView adapter. I'm using LoaderManager callbacks to get updates when the DB values change, which gives me a new cursor. I'm then comparing the new cursor with the one the adapter currently holds to figure out what's changed, switching out the old one with the new one in the adapter, and then calling the appropriate `notifyItem(Range)Inserted/Changed/Removed()` functions. This works great, but there are some places I'd like to use it that can have some pretty big cursors, so I'm hoping to optimize it by figuring out which items are visible using the layout manager and then only checking those items in the cursor for changes instead of checking every single row.

Now my question is, let's say I have a cursor with 1000 rows, and my RecyclerView is showing say rows 0-10. I can go through the cursors, checking the items at index 0-10 for changes/additions/deletions and call the appropriate notify() functions as I'm currently doing, but what about the non-visible items? Do I have to notify the adapter that there may be changes in those rows or can I safely just ignore them and it will just use the updated data when those rows get bound?

Edits for clarity, my code flow is like this:

My adapter holds a cursor, `getItemCount` just returns `cursor.count()` and the `ViewHolder` binding code is along the lines of `cursor.moveToPosition(position)` followed by some things like `ViewHolder.setFoo(cursor.getString(BAR))`

When something changes in the DB, the `LoaderManager` callbacks call `onLoadFinished` with an updated cursor, and then that calls `adapter.changeCursor(newCursor)`

`changeCursor` basically iterates over the old and new cursor to check what's changed. That works fine, but if the cursor is very large it might take some time to loop the whole thing, so I was hoping to be able to skip everything except the visible items. If I do that, changes work fine since `onBindViewHolder` will use the updated cursor, but if a (non-visible) row is added or deleted and I don't call `notifyItemInserted/Removed`, the adapter doesn't know about it and doesn't handle it properly, which leads me to believe that I can't do this optimization, I have to just loop the whole thing to find added/removed rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.

You don't need to concern yourself with the non-visible items.  When the `LayoutManager` eventually places them on-screen, you will get a call to `bindViewHolder` in the adapter.  It is here where you'll reflect the current state of the adapter (which has your cursor) in your view.

Comment: Cool, appreciate the answer. FWIW I've been doing some testing though and it seems that looping over the `RecyclerView`'s children and calling `getChildAdapterPosition` is more stable than getting the visible children from the layout manager. Even that is not 100% though as it seems some views are not re-bound as I would expect, so I've been messing with checking the child positions +- 1 or 2 indices to be safe and stable

Comment: Sorry to unmark this answer but it looks like it's not the case, for example if I am showing items 1-10 with a total of 100, remove the 100th item from the cursor, when I scroll down, I get a crash. Similarly if I am showing items 1-10 with a total of 99 and add a 100th item, only 99 are displayed, even though I have checked and getItemCount is returning the proper number

Comment: No problem.  A couple of things -- if the goal is just to get the visible items to rebind themselves, then all you actually need to do is call `notifyDataSetChanged`.  This will _only_ rebind the visible items.  It doesn't go through every item in the adapter.  As for your other issue with crashing -- can you add relevant sections of bind, create, and `getItemViewType`?  I'd be more than happy to help out.

Comment: BTW, even though I'm asking for code, I'm already certain that the reason only 99 are displayed is because you are not properly calling one of the `notify` methods on your adapter.  `getItemCount` might be correct in a debugger, but there's no reason for the Recycler to call it until it knows there is a change in the adapter.  This is also the reason it crashes when you remove an item.  Without calling `notifyItemRemoved` or `notifyDataSetChanged`, a call to `bindViewHolder` will still be called -- but the position will be invalid.  You'll see this by adding a breakpoint to `bindViewHolder`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured, but I was under the impression I only needed to call `notifyItemRemoved` if the item was visible, it appears that is not the case. My main goal here is to be smart about telling the adapter what's changed by using the `notifyItem` functions so that I get the item animators and don't re bind views that don't need it. Was hoping I could optimize the check by only looking at visible items since I need to iterate the cursor to determine what's changed and the cursor could be large

Comment: I don't think I have any code that would help clarify things, the adapter basically just pulls one row from the cursor for each item and then binds the view based on that information, `getItemCount` returns `cursor.count()`. What happens when things change is that `onLoadFinished` is triggered, which calls a method on the adapter to swap out its current cursor with the new one, and to determine changes it loops over both and compares them, then changes the data backing the adapter and calls appropriate `notify` functions

Comment: I added some more info on my code flow to my original question, I'm thinking that the way to go might be to check the counts of the old/new cursor and then loop the whole thing if the counts are different, and if they're not then only check the visible items

Comment: Even though it might feel like you are doing unnecessary binding, remember that binding only occurs for items that are on-screen.  There is no way to bind an off-screen item (caveat -- this is actually up to the layout manager).  So, if there are three items onscreen, and you call `notifyDatasetChanged`, you will only get three bind calls (give or take depending on possible changes in height).  If you can resolve the cursor position in the bind, you don't have to loop.  Takeaway - don't use `notifyItemChanged` when the # of items that are changing can only be determined through brute force.

Comment: Yep, understood, I just know that from just about every source I've seen, `notifyItemChanged/Added/Removed` is what is described as the "right" way of dong things and `notifyDatasetChanged` is inherently inefficient. I've asked another related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760310/which-is-more-expensive-notifydatasetchanged-or-looping-over-a-large-cursor

Comment: Just saw your edit and the Takeaway is really what I'm looking for, appreciate the help

Comment: Cool!  Best of luck!