# Which is more expensive, notifyDatasetChanged() or looping over a large cursor?

Tags: android, performance, cursor, android-recyclerview, adapter

Basically, I have a RecyclerView with an adapter populating the data from a cursor. I have two options to get item animations:

1. Use `setHasStableIds(true)` and override `getItemId` to return the ID of the database row, and then use a `swapCursor` function in the adapter that swaps its current cursor with the new one and then calls `notifyDatasetChanged`
2. Similar to option 1, but instead of simply swapping the cursor and calling `notifyDatasetChanged`, iterate over the old and new cursor, comparing the rows to determine which rows have been added/deleted/changed and keeping track of them, then calling `notifyItemAdded`, `notifyItemChanged`, etc. to tell the adapter specifically what's been updated

With option 1, `notifyDatasetChanged` will re-bind all the visible items (and some other stuff) which is inefficient, but with option 2 I would have to loop over the full cursor to figure out which items have been added/deleted, and if the cursor is fairly large, this could also take some time. Does anyone have any ideas about which would be the better solution and why?

Edit:

To make things even more interesting, I also have a third option:

3. Similar to option 2, but instead of iterating over every item in the cursor, only iterate over the currently bound items (figured out by checking the `RecyclerView`'s children) since the others will pick up the new cursor values when they're bound. The only problem with this is that it doesn't work for additions/deletions, so the way around it would be to do a full iteration if `oldCursor.count() != newCursor.count()`. If the counts are the same, I can do `setHasStableIds(false)` and then even if the row at a position is different than it was previously, `onBindViewHolder` will take care of it.

Downsides of this would be that the ID's aren't stable, which means the `RecyclerView` will have to do some extra work in some places

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is prone to errors. I would go with option 1, keep it simple.

Comment: I'm not really worried about errors, I've actually written the code for both options and they both work just fine (as well as most of the code for the new option 3), just trying to figure out which one would be the most efficient

Comment: Just add some metrics then, you can use System.nanotime() and take time samples to measure how long your loop takes and how long it takes for the adapter to swap the cursor and refresh the contents.
Alternatively use traceView to get some metrics.